# Slide UP and Down logic - Jquery

Tags: jquery

I wrote below script but it doesnt work like what I expect. I want to slide up or down depends its visibility when click. What is the problem in the script?

```
    <script>
                    jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
                        $(".ddd").click(function () {
  if ( $(".searchform").is( ":hidden" ) ) {
    $(".searchform").slideUp(1000);
        $(".searchform").css("display", "block");
  }  if ( $(".searchform").is( ":visible" ) ) {
    $(".searchform").slideDown(1000);
       $(".searchform").css("display", "hidden");
  }
                        });
                    });
                </script>
```

Comment: you can trick it in this way to also work it for you as expected `.searchform.group{ background: black; width: 101%; }` then the search input use this `width: 100%;` instead of `width: 101%;`... This works perfectly on my localhost

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can Easily use the Jquery Built in Method `slideToggle()` to achieve that without adding additional `hide()` or `show()` method or any css property.

Like in the Example below:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(".add").click(function() {
    $(".searchform").slideToggle();
  });
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<div class="searchform">
  <input type="text" name="" value="">
  <button type="button" name="button">Search</button>
</div>

<button class="add">Hide/Show</button>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: while sliding, searchform width changes.I mean at the finish moment of sliding, suddenly width of searchform is changed to normal width.how can I avoid this width changing?

Comment: shorturl.at/bxRWX

Comment: though it's from your css code an not from the jquery , but i will try to drop some solution here in the next 10 to 20 mins

Comment: i was able to clone your page to a local host and find out that you are hiding an html form once the button is triggered and your css code set a different `width` to the input field itself which is `101%` in your case making it wider than the main html form element itself.. Now once you click the Jquery toggle action, it first of all hide the input tag making it to return only the form element `width` which in your case is smaller than the `input` tag... that's what is happening there.. i will love to help further on this, but let's keep this comment clean, switch to the room let's  talk more.

Comment: you can trick it in this way to also work it for you as expected `.searchform.group{background: black; width: 101%;}` then the search input use this `width: 100%;` instead of `width: 101%;`... This works perfectly on my localhost